# CSS - Set div in top corner and make other divs float around it

Tags: html, css, position, css-position, positioning

I want to have a button float in the top right corner at all times, and the other buttons with dynamic width float around it at the left side and under it aswell.

[image: Example]

The right button is the one which I want to stick, the blue one's can have different width which I cannot control.

**What I've tried:**

1. Setting the red button to `position: absolute` but that made it
   overlap the other buttons
2. Added `padding-right` to surrounding box,
   which forces the space under the red button to be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve it using `float: right` on the red button, and make sure that the red button is the first in the html.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
}
.btn {
  border: 1px solid #99f;
  height: 30px;
  width: 90px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.btn.btn-red {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid #f99;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="btn btn-red"></div>
  <div class="btn"></div>
  <div class="btn"></div>
  <div class="btn"></div>
  <div class="btn"></div>
  <div class="btn"></div>
  <div class="btn"></div>
  <div class="btn"></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! I forgot to mention I tried setting it to `float:right` but I didn't place it first in the html. Will accept as answer when SO allows me :)